# outlines package + minipage error

Tags: errors, lists, itemize, minipage

I'm *happily* using the `outlines` package. I am in the quest to keep an item in the same page. I've tried wrapping it in a `minipage`, and this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section{aSection}
\begin{outline}  
\1 \blindtext[3]
%\2 \blindtext[1]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\1 [$\blacktriangleright$]\emph{\textbf{aTitle}}: \blindtext[3]
\end{minipage}
\1 \blindtext[3]
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

But if the commented line is uncommented  (adding another item to the one before the item in the minipage environment), it will trigger this error:

```
 ! LaTeX Error: \begin{minipage} on input line 13 ended by \end{itemize}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14 \1
        [$\blacktriangleright$]\emph{\textbf{aTitle}}: \blindtext[3]
?
```

So, any chance I can do what I want ? Or I'm lost ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Allow me to tell you that you have posted a perfect question, especially for a newbie!

Comment: Thanks ! I guess you can blame it on using TeX.SE to learn tex, and I use SE a lot in general (other communities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the start of the `minipage` environment does not end the `\2` outline command. This is ended by the `\1` you put inside the `minipage` making it going across the start of the `minipage` which causes TeX to raise an error since the `minipage` environment, being defined *inside* the `\2` should be entirely included in it.

One simple, but perhaps boring solution, is to separate the outlines, ie:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section{aSection}
\begin{outline}  
\1[sss] \blindtext[3]
\2 \blindtext[1]
\end{outline}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{outline}
\1 [$\blacktriangleright$]\emph{\textbf{aTitle}}: \blindtext[3]
\end{outline}
\end{minipage}
\begin{outline}
\1 \blindtext[3]
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this works indeed. Nevertheless, it mess up with custom spacing I left out  of my MWE. I will edit the question to include it.

Comment: @cladelpino only if you feel that the question remains the same

Comment: roger. I will do it separately then

Comment: @cladelpino it's up to you, really.

Comment: Actually, it has a very weird interaction with \usepackage{parskip}.